# How to convert 200 bag of word features to several continuous features

Tags: regression, prediction

I am using one text dataset for regression task. The baseline regression method (name concealed) that I employ will work well if all the input features are continuous.  However, the text dataset that I am considering has 200 bag-of-word features that are binary (0, or 1), i.e the first feature will be 1 if the associated word appearing on the text and 0 otherwise. I am just curious how can I convert those 200 binary to one or several continuous features such that my regressor can work with.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Latent dirichlet allocation (LDA) would be a good one to try, as it is tailored for bag-of-words representations. LDA is a *topic model*, which basically means that it assigns $n$ topics, and figures out the words that associate with each topic. The output is a vector of $n$ continuous values where each value indicates membership to the corresponding topic. You should be able to find an implementation of LDA for whatever language you're using easily (but don't confuse it with linear discriminant analysis, also commonly referred to as LDA).

You could also try principal components analysis or singular value decompositions, which are other standard dimensionality reduction techniques.